# Cancel stream when onClick, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, onclick

The idea behind what I want to do is to break/finish a function once I run the very same function again, but with different parameters.

Right now I have a stream of random characters being sent to an endpoint.

A class gets this endpoint and allows the stream to populate a content view.

I have a tab that calls this population function every time I click on it.

I would like it so that when I click another tab or the same tab, the function ends, stops using the previous parameters, and then runs the function again with the new parameters. In the case of clicking the same tab it would simply do nothing.

Below I have the HTML body, the CSS, the JS script for the client side, and the node.js server side that sends the stream. You should be able to more or less copy paste this and it will run.

Don't forget to npm install for the node. Just run the node code to start the server.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tab-bar">
        <button class="tab" onclick="getStreamNContentLocale('stream_1')">London</button>
        <button class="tab" onclick="getStreamNContentLocale('stream_2')">Paris</button>
        <button class="tab" onclick="getStreamNContentLocale('stream_3')">Tokyo</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="stream_1">
        </div>
        <div id="stream_2">
        </div>
        <div id="stream_3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.tab-bar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}

.tab {
    color: white;
    font-size: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding: 9px 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
console.log((new Date()).toLocaleString());

function getStreamNContentLocale(contentID) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        streamArray = [],
        snapshotsSent = 0;

    xhr.open('GET', `/stream`);
    xhr.seenBytes = 0;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState > 2) {
            if (snapshotsSent < 30) {
                streamArray.push("Snapshot sent " + (new Date()).toLocaleString() + "\n" + xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.seenBytes, xhr.responseText.length));
                document.querySelector(`#${contentID}`).innerText = streamArray;
            } else if (snapshotsSent >= 30) {
                streamArray.shift();
                streamArray.push("Snapshot sent " + (new Date()).toLocaleString() + "\n" + xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.seenBytes, xhr.responseText.length));
                document.querySelector(`#${contentID}`).innerText = streamArray;
            }
            xhr.seenBytes = xhr.responseText.length;
        }
        snapshotsSent++;
        /**********************************************************************************************
         * xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.seenBytes, xhr.responseText.length) is each snapshot we GET *
         * snapshotsSent is the number of snapshots we have actually gotten so far in this session    *
         **********************************************************************************************/
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

**server:**

```
let express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    path = require('path');

init(function() {
        callback(null);
    });

function init(callback) {
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
    }));

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../../views")));

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../../views/index.html"));
    });

    app.get('/stream', (req, res) => {
        console.log('sending stream to /stream');
        setInterval(() => {
            res.write(Math.random(16).toString(36).substring(2) + "\n");
        }, 200);
    });

    app.listen(8000, () => {
        console.log("Listening on port 8000");
    });

    callback();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `XMLHttpRequest xhr` in the function itself and abort it each time you run the function. Like this (in your JS file):

```
function getStreamNContentLocale(contentID) {

    if( getStreamNContentLocale.xhr !== undefined)
        getStreamNContentLocale.xhr.abort();

    getStreamNContentLocale.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        streamArray = [],
        snapshotsSent = 0;

    // the rest of your code goes here
}
```

See `abort()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort

EDIT: also add `getStreamNContentLocale.xhr = undefined;` in your callback, else it may return an error when aborting a finished request.

Comment: Ah, so like every time I run the function it checks to see if the stream is already running via checking to see if `getStreamNContentLocale.xhr` is defined or not. Right?

Comment: Exactly :)
Don't forget to valid this answer if it was what you needed.

Comment: We shall see, I'm testing this now.

Comment: If you want to do that cleanly you can also add `getStreamNContentLocale.xhr = undefined;` in your callback. Else it may return an error when aborting a finished request.

Comment: So this did not work. It was not actually aborting anything because getStreamNContentLocalel.xhr was not assigned before hand. I ended up fixing this with something like this:

`if( window.lwsxhr !== undefined) {
    console.log("aborting");
        window.lwsxhr.abort();
        window.lwsxhr.onreadystatechange = () => {};
        window.lwsxhr = undefined;
      }`

where `window.lwsxhr = xhr;`

Comment: Sadly this ^^^ still does not work. I run into a problem with it when once I've click every tab at least once, clicking a previous tab again will only abort the stream and then do nothing.